# Angular-ui bootstrap datepicker "Today" button sends date in wrong format to the backend

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

We are using Angular-ui bootstrap datepicker as following :

```
template : '<div class="datepicker"> <input grid-cell-validatable type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="cell.value" is-open="opened" min="minDate" ng-disabled="row.readonly" date-input-parser/> <button class="btn btn-mini btn-calendar icon-calendar" ng-click="open()"></button> </div>'
```

When i select date using calender date cell, it sends date in "dd-MMMM-yyyy" format but If I select date using "Today" button from the footer, it shows the date selection in the UI cell as "dd-MMMM-yyyy" format but in the java class in backend the format is sent as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".

How can I fix this and get "dd-MMMM-yyyy" format everywhere.

When I debug using Firebug, on click of "Today" button the value itself is getting set in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format though on UI I see "dd-MMMM-yyyy" date in the cell. How do I change this setting and also set the value in "dd-MMMM-yyyy" format?

Comment: How are you sending it to the backend?

Comment: I looked more into it and it seems the display value for date cell is in "dd-MMMM-yyyy" format but If I open firebug and check the value set for the cell it is in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format. So I need to fix this in UI and not in the backend. I also updated the question with details. Kindly advise.